# How to prevent RabbitMQ settings to be lost during intermediate steps of a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile, rabbitmqctl

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that runs RabbitMQ with a predefined user, but during the Dockerfile build steps the settings are lost.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:management
# Set node name to try to avoid settings being lost during intermediate containers creation
RUN echo "NODENAME=rabbit@localhost" > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
# Start server in intermediate container and configure user
RUN rabbitmq-server -detached \
    && sleep 5 \  
    && rabbitmqctl add_user test test \ 
    && rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test management \ 
    && rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*" \
    && rabbitmqctl list_users
# Start server in intermediate container just to show that user configuration is lost
RUN rabbitmq-server -detached \
    && sleep 5 \  
    && rabbitmqctl list_users
# Run server in final container as main/daemon process
CMD rabbitmq-server
```

The commands I'm using to build the image and run the container are:

```
docker build -t rabbitmq:test .
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:test
```

I'm using boot2docker to run the containers, in a Windows machine, but it does not seem to be relevant.

The output shows that after each Dockerfile step, when an intermediate container is created, the settings are lost.

Does anyone know how to fix it? I'm stuck on it for two days now.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some alternatives, I got this working using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:management
CMD rabbitmq-server -detached ; \
    sleep 3 ; \  
    rabbitmqctl add_user test test ; \ 
    rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test management ; \ 
    rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
    rabbitmqctl stop ; \
    sleep 3 ; \  
    rabbitmq-server
```

It does not solve the original problem, but at least I have a RabbitMQ container configured as I need.